# Condition not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to make one function which sends FCM notification based on my condition.

My code

```
$number = $_GET["number"];
$status = $_GET["status"];
$userIds = $_GET["userId"];
$sql = "";
for($i = 0; $i < count($number); $i++) {
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO number_status (number, number_status, user_id) VALUES ('$number[$i]', $status[$i], $userIds[$i]);";
   if($status[$i] == 1) {
        $sqlSelect = "SELECT t2.name, t1.fcm, t1.fcm_enabled FROM user AS t1 INNER JOIN number_list AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.user_id WHERE t2.number = '$number[$i]'AND t2.user_id = $userIds[$i]";
        $resultSelect = $conn->query($sqlSelect);
        if($resultSelect) {
            while($row = $resultSelect->fetch_row()) {
                if($row[2] == 1) {
                    sendFCM(array("title" => $row[0] . " is Online", "body" => "",'priority'=>'high'), array("message" => ""), $row[1]);
                }
               else if($row[2] == 0) {
                    sendFCM(array("title" => $row[0] . " is offline", "body" => "",'priority'=>'high'), array("message" => ""), $row[1]);
                }
            }
        }
 }
}
```

I want send online notification if status=1, and I want say offline notification if status=0, but it's always sending notification for online only.

Comment: is `status` column name in user table or number_list table?

Comment: @ status column is in number_list table. Thanks

Comment: i have updated the answer, please check it and i don't know what are the column available in your user table and which column you are using for the `sendFCM` function. check it and if the column name wrong.. update with your column name.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlSelect = "SELECT t2.name, t1.fcm, t1.fcm_enabled, t2.status FROM user AS t1 INNER JOIN number_list AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.user_id WHERE t2.number = '$number[$i]'AND t2.user_id = $userIds[$i]";
$resultSelect = $conn->query($sqlSelect);
if($resultSelect) {
    while($row = $resultSelect->fetch_assoc()) {
        switch($row['status']){
            case 0 :
                sendFCM(array("title" => $row['name'] . " is offline", "body" => "",'priority'=>'high'), array("message" => ""), $row['fcm']);
            break;
            case 1 :
                sendFCM(array("title" => $row['name'] . " is Online", "body" => "",'priority'=>'high'), array("message" => ""), $row['fcm']);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! its still stuck in first condition. Thanks

Comment: are you sure about the status column in number_list table .??

Comment: I think status column not in the number_list table I'm adding another answer just try with that

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($number); $i++) {
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO number_status (number, number_status, user_id) VALUES ('$number[$i]', $status[$i], $userIds[$i]);";
    $sqlSelect = "SELECT t2.name, t1.fcm, t1.fcm_enabled FROM user AS t1 INNER JOIN number_list AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.user_id WHERE t2.number = '$number[$i]'AND t2.user_id = $userIds[$i]";
    $resultSelect = $conn->query($sqlSelect);
    if($resultSelect) {     
        while($row = $resultSelect->fetch_row()) {
            switch($status[$i]){
                case 0 :
                    sendFCM(array("title" => $row[0] . " is offline", "body" => "",'priority'=>'high'), array("message" => ""), $row[1]);
                break;
                case 1 :
                    sendFCM(array("title" => $row[0] . " is Online", "body" => "",'priority'=>'high'), array("message" => ""), $row[1]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```